# Could a red dwarf be "deionized"?

Tags: stellar-astrophysics, plasma-physics

Even the smallest red dwarf stars have [amazing flares](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.syfy.com/syfy-wire/good-news-immensely-powerful-red-dwarf-superflares-may-not-sterilize-their-planets%3famp). But the photosphere temperature can be as low as 2700K, which (I think) is too cool to ionize hydrogen. Even the sun at 5800K is cool enough that most of the hydrogen is not ionized.

The plasma must come from the corona. Which is in turn kept very hot due to resistive heating from currents induced by fluctuating magnetic fields.

If this plasma was removed there would be no such heating. Could this stop the star from having flares?

My guess is no: all it takes is a single ion in the rarefied upper atmosphere to get the process started. It would be accelerated to a very high speed and smash into neutral hydrogen, liberating more ions in a chain reaction.

Comment: Hard to know what you are asking. The stars you refer to undergoing large flares are not cool enough to have no free electrons and they don't just come from hydrogen, but from sodium and potassium. The magnetic fields in the corona are jostled by motion of coronal loop footpoints, which does require some coupling between the photosphere and the magnetic field. The stressed fields accelerate particles, release energy and drive flares. Other mechanisms have been proposed for even cooler objects (brown dwarfs).

Comment: @ProfRob: Below 3000K (recombination) even an extremely dilute hydrogen gas has little ionization. But sodium takes less than half the energy to ionize, so it should ionize at even the coolest photosphere temperatures. Makes me wonder if the first M-dwarfs which formed would (after burning their Big-Bang lithium) have more trouble generating plasma and flares?

Comment: Sodium has an ionization energy of about 5 eV, which corresponds  to a temperature of about $6*10^4 K$ . Below that temperature you would not ionize anything,

Comment: @Thomas: Water has a vaporization energy of about 0.42 eV per molecule, corresponding to 4800K. But water boils at a much lower temperature and evaporates at a meaningful rate down to ~225 K.

Comment: You were talking about ionization not vaporization.

Comment: @Thomas: Why would the thermodynamics be fundamentally different? Both involve adding one extra particle to the gaseous phase which causes a drastic rise in entropy.

Answer (score 1):

The average gravitational potential and kinetic (via the virial theorem) energy of a particle in the solar plasma is of the order of 1 keV (corresponding to a temperature of about $10^7 K$). The particle energies for a red dwarf will not be much lower as both the mass and radius are reduced by about the same factor compared to the Sun and the gravitational potential energy $\propto M/R$ . The mass/radius ratio would have to be less than about a 1/100 of that of the Sun for the plasma energy be less than the ionization energy of 13.6 eV (Jupiter just about falls below this limit, with a hydrogen atom at its surface having a gravitational energy of about 10 eV).  The photospheric temperature is pretty much irrelevant for this. The photosphere is just a thin layer where the plasma density is small enough so that bound atoms can form and which is cooled by inelastic collisions. A small amount of high energy particles will be able to penetrate the photosphere from below though, especially in regions where it is thinner.

Comment: The virial theorem does not apply to coronal plasma, which is not in equilibrium - obviously so in the case of flares. And if it did, you would have to include a magnetic energy term. The temperature of 1 keV is largely determined by a minimum in the radiative loss function, so that's where most of the cooling, dynamic plasma accumulates, before cooling more rapidly at lower temperatures.

Comment: @ProfRob The Sun as a whole is in a (quasi)-hydrostatic equilibrium. This implies an average particle energy in the Sun of the order of 1 keV. This also matches pretty closely the energy in the solar corona and solar wind. It is only the energy in the photosphere which is considerably different from this.